# YARN - Possible values for "Resource­Manager Web UI" port

Tags: rest, port, hadoop-yarn, dart-webui, resourcemanager

Is the port for "Resource­Manager Web UI" for a yarn machine always set to 8088 or is it possible to change it?

I see here in the [documentation of hortonworks](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDP2Alpha/index.htm#Appendix/Ports_Appendix/YARN_Ports.htm) that the default value is 8088, but it is not written whether it could have different values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup the WebUI address in `yarn-default.xml` file.

Set property `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address` to another port.

For more detailed information refer to the documentation
http://docs.hortonworks.com/Hadoop2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 3):

With last version of YARN as of now (Oct 2018), default port is 8088:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml